# How to create a neat AJAX enabled with ASP.Net MVC web application

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am new to ASP.Net MVC. I am trying to create  a google type of search functionality for my drop down list, which has a hugh amount of data. It means when I type the characters the related search items will be filtered. I am not finding the correct parth to do it in ASP.NET MVC environment.This is part of a Data entry form. The form has a submit button. Please guide me with some neat samples to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you're actually looking to use the ASP.NET Ajax toolkit, but here are 2 great examples.

Using jQuery:
http://flux88.com/blog/jquery-auto-complete-text-box-with-asp-net-mvc/

Using .NET AJAX:
http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2008/08/24/asp-net-mvc-tip-37-create-an-auto-complete-text-field.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I'd highly recommend jQuery over ASP.NET Ajax. jQuery is simpler to integrate and has a "lighter" footprint.